# WEB API Forms Authentication - Where can i set Roles for a User

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I use this Login Action:

```
    // POST api/login
    public bool Post(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (model.Username == "user" && model.Password == "password")
        {
            var princ = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(model.Username), null);

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username,false);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and i have set authentication to forms. Everything works fine so far, except i have no idea how i would set the roles for the currently authenticated user, so i can use this Attribute:

```
[Authorize (Roles = "Admin")]
```

Answer (score 1):

From Visual Studio click the `Project` menu and select `ASP.NET Configuration`. This will launch the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool. From here you can add/edit Users and their security roles.

If you see an error message on the Security tab then you will probably need to do some additional configuration. Here is a handy walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented RoleProvider you need not worry about setting role to the principal .

Other option is to pass in roles to directly to  generic principal.

```
string[] roles = { "Admin", "role2", "role3" };
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(httpContext.User.Identity, roles);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use

```
[Authorize(Roles="manager, admin")]
```

etc

Refer to http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api  more details

Comment: I know i can do that, but i don't know where i can set the roles of the user.

Comment: Launch ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool as mentioned by Jeremiah above. You will be able see the current users etc.